# Rendering Table with conditional color in latex as a pdf document with rownames = TRUE (rmarkdown, kable and kableExtra )

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, r-rownames

I am attempting to output a latex table using r markdown, kable and kableExtra. When i use the option row.names=FALSE instead of row.names=TRUE the latex code generates \vphantom code which produce an error to create the pdf .
It seems the problem is linked to the row_spec option.

Here is  Rmarkdown code (.Rmd File):

```
---
title: "Test"
output:
pdf_document: 
fig_caption: true
keep_tex: true
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)


{r}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

temp <- mtcars[1:5,1:5]

kable(temp, format = "latex", booktabs = F,row.names=F)  %>%
kable_styling(position = "center") %>%
row_spec(1, bold = T, background = "red")
```

The error is:

> ! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of
> \check@nocorr@. 
> \par  l.105 ...color{red}  \textbf{21.0 &\vphantom{1} 6}
> & \textbf{160} & \textbf{...

What is happening?

Comment: It works on my computer. Have you tried with `bold=F` to see what happens?

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the duplicated rows in the dataframe, as both rows 1 and 2 are the same.

Reviewing the code for [row_spec_latex](https://github.com/cran/kableExtra/blob/master/R/row_spec.R), when kableExtra is used against a kable table, it checks for duplicated rows. If it finds one, it inserts the `vphantom` argument within the [fix_duplicated_rows_latex](https://github.com/cran/kableExtra/blob/master/R/util.R) internal function. This vphantom insertion is then messing up the formatting of the `textbf` function.

This seems like a slight bug, so it may be worth reporting it as an issue in kableExtra: https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra . I am sure that the `vphantom` is added for a good reason though, but doubt this was an intended consequence.

**Supporting code:**

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
temp <- mtcars[1:5,1:5]
```

```{r}
# Keeping the row names (means all rows are unique)
kable(temp, format = "latex", booktabs = F)  %>%
  kable_styling(position = "center") %>%
  row_spec(1, bold = T, color = "red")
```

```{r}
# Highlighting second row (which doesn't have the vphantom statement)
kable(temp, format = "latex", booktabs = F, row.names=F)  %>%
  kable_styling(position = "center") %>%
  row_spec(2, bold = T, color = "red")
```
````

[image]

Comment: I reported the error to github in kableExtra. Thanks a lot for your help !